# Как создать файл с расширением .exe

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! С java знаком не так давно. Постепенно осваиваю. Не подскажете, как получить файл с расширением .exe? Другими словами создать полноценную сборку, чтобы запустить написанную программу в Eclise.

Comment: @Александр1111, аналогичный вопрос уже был: http://hashcode.ru/questions/301174/eclipse-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-exe-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: @Александр1111, да и так-то после компиляции в *.jar Вы также получаете полноценную сборку, только вместо *.exe *.jar. Двойной клик в любой системе, где установлена jre приведет к запуску исполняемого *.jar:)

Comment: Здравствуйте, файл с расширением .exe создаётся с помощью программы-эмулятора.

Comment: Не подскажите как пользоваться Launch4j3.5, какие параметры необходимо ввести чтобы он стартовал, что-то он не желает запускаться.

Comment: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html - в доках уже были?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри вот здесь вроде нормально описано, даже видосы есть

http://javabegin.ru/faq/javainstaller1.html

http://javabegin.ru/tools/javainstaller2.html

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно сделать exe-файл, который не будет завязан на Java-рантайм (Launch4j всё равно будет требовать наличие JRE), то можно использовать Excelsior JET: http://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate

Это полноценный статический ahead-of-time компилятор Java, который компилирует jar в нативный exe-файл.

К сожалению, инструмент является платным и стоит $3000, однако есть триальный период в 90 дней.

Comment: Кстати, сейчас можно купить Excelsior JET всего за $50: http://www.excelsiorjet.com/charity