# Можно ли компилировать код, написанный на Java, в машинный код?

Tags: java

Возможно ли такое? чтобы ускорить работу. Чтобы получить машинный код и далее хранить её в таком виде.

Comment: вы хотите сделать исполняемый файл для разных систем? андроид так же выполняет байт-код, а не машинный, в этом плане он не отличается. если нужна скорость, то надо писать на си.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman На самом деле вопрос адекватный и вы преждевременно человека "посылаете на `C`". Потому что, к примеру, в .NET есть утилита Ngen.exe, трансформирующая готовую программу (это тоже байт-код) в нативный код.

Comment: Подобные вопросы:    http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301174/Как-сделать-exe-файл-из-java-файла    http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/59618/exe-файл-в-java    http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/386487/Как-создать-файл-с-расширением-exe    http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603543/Создание-exe-файла-для-проекта-intellij-idea

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я никого никуда не посылал. Я задал наводящий вопрос. И пояснил, что в андроид так же работает как и JVM.

Comment: В JVM уже встроен механизм компиляции в машинный код и это происходит автоматически. Эта особенность называется JIT. Если какой-то байт-код выполняется несколько раз, то он компилируется в машинный. Но я говорю именно про JVM, а не про Dalvik. Как это устроено Dalvik, я не знаю.

Comment: Интересно, можно ли в андроид не использовать JVM , а писать сразу исполняемые файлы. Под виндовс например можно.

Answer (score 0):

Программа на Java компилируется в байт код понятный для JVM, после запуска приложения под JVM код собственно транспилиться в машинный код для выполнения на железе, только Вас это уже не касаеться. Таким образом Java добивается кроссплатформенности.

Comment: Вы как будто даже вопрос не читали. Я как раз таки хочу отказаться от кросплатформенности на Java. Хочу компилятор, который компилирует не в байт код, а в нативный для каждой операционной системы свой компилятор.